# Typescript module behaviour

Tags: typescript

In the following module foo, `bar.factoryMethod('Blue')` returns an instance of `WidgetBlue`.

```
module foo {

  export class bar {
    factoryMethod(classname: string): WidgetBase {
      return new foo["Widget" + classname]();
    }
  }

  export class WidgetBase {
    A: number;
    B: string;
  }

  export class WidgetBlue extends WidgetBase { }

  export class WidgetRed extends WidgetBase { }

}
```

The point of this arrangement, which works well, is plug-in widgets.

Unfortunately, when I declare a plug-in `WidgetGreen` *in another file* things rapidly go south.

```
module foo {

  export class WidgetGreen extends WidgetBase { }

}
```

For some reason `WidgetGreen` is out of scope at run-time within `factoryMethod`. Moving it to the same file resolves the problem, but this is no good for plug-in classes - they would have to be added to the same file.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991382/typescript-modules) suggests that my code ought to work, but it doesn't. Why? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the base class must be loaded first and the factory must be loaded last. With the base class and the factory in the same file this is impossible.

However, there is no requirement for the base class to be in the same file as the factory, it's merely an accident of development. Splitting the module into *three* files allows loading in dependency order:

1. Base class and core derivatives
2. Plug-in derivatives of the base class
3. Factory

A better approach decorates the base class with a collection and a RegisterType method that accepts a class reference and associates it with a data type string name. Each class declaration can be followed with a registration of the class. The factory becomes a static method on the base class, with access to the collection of registered types. This approach is slightly more complex but much easier to maintain, placing fewer requirements on users of the library code.